# Only first posts featured image is shown

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a custom template for WordPress. I can add multiple featured images in a single post and can show them as a gallery or slider. 
Everything works fine on the first post.

When I add my second post with 2 or more featured images it does not display any image at all if I have only 1 featured image it shows.

Can anyone review my code and tell me what am I missing:

**EDIT**

```
<?php /* Template Name: Home v4 */ get_template_part('/template-parts/home4_header'); ?>            

    <section class="background-color">

        <?php query_posts('showposts=0'); ?>    
        <?php $i = 1; ?>            
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if(($i % 4) !== 0) { ?>

        <!-- Fixed width banner -->
        <div class="container">             
            <div class="containerBox">

                <!-- Multiple Featured Images Slider -->        
                <?php
                if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {                              
                // Loops through each feature image and grabs thumbnail URL

                $x=1; $image1_id; $image2_id; $image3_id; $image4_id; $image5_id;

                    while ($x<=5) {
                        $image_name = 'feature-image-'.$x;  // sets image name as feature-image-1, feature-image-2 etc.
                        if (MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail('post', $image_name)) { 
                            $image_id = MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id( 'post', $image_name, $post->ID );  // use the MultiPostThumbnails to get the image ID
                            $image_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id,'small-thumb');  // define thumb src based on image ID
                            $image_feature_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id,'feature-image' ); // define full size src based on image ID
                            $attr = array(
                                'rel' => $image_thumb_url[0],   // sets the url for the image thumbnails size
                                'src' => $image_feature_url[0], // sets the url for the full image size 
                            );                                                                                      
                            // Use wp_get_attachment_image instead of standard MultiPostThumbnails to be able to tweak attributes
                            $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'feature-image', false, $attr );               
                            //echo $image;

                            if ($x == 1) {$image1_id = $image_id;}
                            if ($x == 2) {$image2_id = $image_id;}
                            if ($x == 3) {$image3_id = $image_id;}
                            if ($x == 4) {$image4_id = $image_id;}
                            if ($x == 5) {$image5_id = $image_id;}
                        }                           
                        $x++;
                    }                            

                }; // end if MultiPostThumbnails                                    


                if (!empty($image2_id)) { ?>
                <div class="multi-thumb">   
                    <div id="ninja-slider">
                        <div class="slider-inner">
                            <ul>    
                                <li>
                                    <div class="slider">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="slider">
                                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image2_id, 'feature-image', false, $attr );?>">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <?php if (!empty($image3_id)) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="slider">
                                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image3_id, 'feature-image', false, $attr );?>">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if (!empty($image4_id)) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="slider">
                                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image4_id, 'feature-image', false, $attr );?>">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if (!empty($image5_id)) { ?>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="slider">
                                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image5_id, 'feature-image', false, $attr );?>">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <?php } ?>      
                            </ul>
                        <div class="fs-icon" title="Expand/Close"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      
                <?php 
                unset($image1_id, $image2_id, $image3_id, $image4_id, $image5_id, $image_name, $image, $image_thumb_url, $image_feature_url);

                } else { the_post_thumbnail('full'); } ?>
                <!-- End Multiple Featured Images Slider -->            
            </div>  

            <div class="post-area-category container-post-color bottom-padding">
                <div class="content-block w-clearfix">
                    <div class="category">  
                        <h5><?php echo the_category();?></h5> 
                    </div>
                    <h1 class="black mastheading-post-v3"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    <div class="date-block-v3 w-container">
                        <div class="black mini-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>
                        <img class="mini-icon" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/comment-icon.png' ?>">
                        <div class="black mini-date">
                            <?php 
                            $comments_count = wp_count_comments();
                            echo $comments_count->approved;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <img class="mini-icon" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/heart-icon.png' ?>">
                        <div class="black mini-date">14</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="black iltalica"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                    <a class="a8 cta-home-category w-button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">continue reading</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="space-4 background-color"></div>    
        </div>
        <!-- Fixed width banner -->

        <?php } elseif (($i % 4) == 0) { ?>

            <!-- Full width banner -->
            <div class="container-fluid">               
                <div class="containerBox">
                    <div class="home-v3-full-banner">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container post-area-category container-post-color bottom-padding">
            <div class="content-block w-clearfix">
                <div class="category">  
                    <h5><?php echo the_category();?></h5> 
                </div>
                <h1 class="black mastheading-post-v3"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                <div class="date-block-v3 w-container">
                    <div class="black mini-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>
                    <img class="mini-icon" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/comment-icon.png' ?>">
                    <div class="black mini-date">
                        <?php 
                            $comments_count = wp_count_comments();
                            echo $comments_count->approved;
                            ?>
                    </div>
                    <img class="mini-icon" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/heart-icon.png' ?>">
                    <div class="black mini-date">14</div>
                </div>
                <div class="black iltalica"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                <a class="a8 cta-home-category w-button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">continue reading</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Full width banner -->


        <?php } ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>

        <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: can you post your full code?. I mean template page code. I think something you made mistake in  $i = 1; or $x. Im but sure.

Comment: @vel code is added for this page...

Comment: I added 3 images for second post seems working fine.

Comment: Yes it works... t

Comment: Yes it works... but try to add 2nd post with 2 or 3 images

Comment: You mean 2nd and 3rd feature image

Comment: No. I know that on the first post it works... but when I add second post with multiple images it doesn't work... i get only text.. no images

Comment: It's display for second post also

Comment: is multiple featured images plugin?

Comment: Yes it is a plugin... 
As you told it works on second post as well. The problem was with my css. Images were hidden... After changing my CSS I saw that my code was working good.

Comment: ok fine. your sound is good.

Comment: Your comment helped me. When you said it works! 
Thank you

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Not tested

```
        <?php query_posts('showposts=0'); ?>    

        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php $i = 1; ?>
```